# Back up MySQL using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, ide, phpmyadmin, backup, restore

I have used MySQL for my application written by PHP. After a time its data will be great and I need to make a backup from them. Also, I need I can restore the backup data whenever I need. My question is if phpMyAdmin can make backup and resotore it secure and completely without any data lose?

(I have both MyISAM and innoDB in my database structore)

Also, if you know any other IDE to make backup and restore it without showing the database structures and tables to the end-user, please tell me their names.

Thank you.

Comment: you can use Adminer to make the backup/restore

it's like phpMyAdmin, but in a single file (easy installation), with friendlier interface a and faster. take a look at www.adminer.org

Comment: Heidi SQL is another good utility to take a look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running MySQL on your own server you may copy the database folder, but the MySQL server would have to be stopped first. Anyway I'd recommend dumping the databases through phpMyAdmin (export function) or via the command line (`mysqldump`). Using the latter, you may write a batch script that also compresses and encrypts the content of the dump file.

Comment: Thank you Tomas and Alasjo for your suggestions. As Derek mentioned, I think something like Workbench can meet my needs. Also, Navicat is a another IDE that I found it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Using the built in Import and Export? The only data loss would be everything after the backup until the time the backup was imported.

Securely? That's an entirely different topic. There's too many things to consider to call anything secure but if you're using https or on a trusted LAN, then yes, I guess it's secure.

I think MySQL Workbench can do exports and imports.

Answer (score 0):

If would you wish to backup MySQL database more securely and periodically without loss of data to remote server or local drive (local hard disk or mapped drive), then you can try Vembu StoreGrid http://www.vembu.com/, a leading backup software trusted by more than 2700 service providers world wide. Once you configured single backup by selecting entire database then automatically newly added database will be backedup on upon next backup time. Also, StoreGrid backups only the incremental bytes of changes on next incremental schedule.

Vembu has a solution for almost everyone, just check them  below:

For Service Providers : StoreGrid Service Provider Edition
For Business/Offices : StoreGrid Professional Edition
For Home Users: Vembu Home
For Resellers who don't want to have their own storage : Vembu Pro
For Hosting Providers: StoreGrid Hosting Provider Edition (yet to be released)

For your requirement, we would suggest the Professional Edition http://storegrid.vembu.com/online-backup/network-backup.php of StoreGrid. Try it!!!

Regards,
Thileepan
vembu.com